# iOS didFailWithError and calling dismissViewController causing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

So my setup is very simple I have:

Controller A
Controller B

Controller A segue's to Controller B, and it's a modal display.

When Controller B's viewDidLoad fires, I instantiate the NSURLConnection with request and start immediately.

If there's no network connection, then the didFailWithError gets fired.

From within here, i call dismissViewController, but when I do, I receive:

"Attempt to dismiss from view controller while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!"

What could possibly be causing this error?

I also have a button on Controller B, that when clicked also does the dismissViewController, but it does it correctly.

Could this be a race condition where Controller B has not finished animating/displaying once it hits viewDidLoad, and the URL connection spawning and failing immediately?

If this is the case, what's the correct way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dismiss a view controller until it has been completely presented.  If you're still in `viewDidLoad`, this certainly isn't going to be the case, and I think this mostly will not be the case in `viewWillAppear`.  `viewDidAppear` is the earliest possible state you can guarantee the view controller's presentation is complete and ready to be dismissed.

With that said... it's better from a UI perspective to instead try to start the `NSURLConnection` in the background and if you have a good network connection, then you present view controller B, and if not, simply never present it, rather than present and immediately dismiss.

Comment: I agree with not presenting controllerB when there is no network connection. However I would like to point out that the animation is still ongoing in viewDidAppear. You can check this through `[self isBeingPresented]`. A solution to this problem is to make controllerB be its navigationControllers delegate. Then you could simply override `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` and dismiss in there. I would still go with what @nhgrif suggested though.

Comment: Good points.  vegethar.  It gets kind of complicated figured out exactly when the earliest possible moment you can dismiss a view controller is, and realistically, if you're looking for this moment, the real answer is to not present in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone. I figured that much it would of been a life cycle issue. I'll try switching to viewDidAppear then. I think the way I am using NSURLConnection is that the request is already being made on a background thread, otherwise my UI would be locking up, and according to the docs, that is the case when you're initing with request, it's async on it's own background thread

Comment: I agree that you should avoid showing it before hand, however there could be just those very marginal times when you've did a check for connection and just as you're in my scenario it also errors out, then we'll need to account for that too.

Comment: If erroring out means dismissing the view controller also, then the entry download should be completed before presenting the view controller, and then the downloaded data sent as an `NSData` object to the presented controller when the download completes successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be race condition. Can you try doing this in failToLoad delegate and see?

```
//Goes into the failed delegate
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //dismiss the View Controller here??
});
```